# Построчное считывание данных из текстового файла и вывод на экран

Tags: c#, файлы

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста. Я вот написал для себя тренировочный код, который бы построчно считывал данные из текстового файла и выводил на экран. Создал текстовый файл, состоящий из 5 строк на англ. языке. Однако когда запускаю программу, то отображается пустой экран.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

```
static void Main()
{
    StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(@"D:\1.txt");
    string s = "";
    while (s != null)
    {
        s = fs.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Вы в цикле перебрали все строки, а когда условие `s != null` не выполнилось, Вы выводите `s`, т.е. `null`. Поэтому Вы ничего и не видите на экране.

Comment: Исправьте  строку s = fs.ReadLine(); на s += fs.ReadLine(); и посмотрите что будет.

Comment: Точно! Понял... Спасибо большое, господа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static void Main()
{ 
    string text = "";

    using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(@"D:\1.txt"))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Читаем строку из файла во временную переменную.
            string temp = fs.ReadLine();

            // Если достигнут конец файла, прерываем считывание.
            if(temp == null) break;

            // Пишем считанную строку в итоговую переменную.
            text  += temp;
        }
     }

     // Выводим на экран.
     Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string line;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\1.txt");
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
 Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить `using` для `sr` на случай, если кто-то скопипастит этот код в середину программы.

Comment: присваивание в проверке условия не очень выглядит, лучше просто проверять конец потока

Comment: @Grundy: Покатит, это [стандартная идиома](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7).

Comment: @VladD, но от этого она не выглядит лучше :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Ничего не поделаешь :-) В следующей версии языка будет что-то наподобие `while (sr.ReadLine() is string! line) Console.WriteLine(line);` (без предварительного объявления `line`)

Comment: @VladD, а зачем если можно просто проверить `sr.EndOfStream`?

Comment: @Grundy: Можно, но это ж две функции, а так то же самое, но одна. Вопрос вкуса, да.

Answer (score 4):

```
        static void Main()
        {
            StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(@"D:\1.txt");
            string s = "";
            while (s != null)
            {
                s = fs.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

и все увидите. После нажатия любой кнопки программа завершится.

Answer (score 3):

Код для формы с элементом textbox

```
 string text;
     using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(string path)//string path - путь к файлу
         while (!read.EndOfStream) // читаем пока файл не закончится
             textBox1.Text += read.ReadLine() + "\r\n"; //выводим все построчно
```

Код для консоли таков

```
using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(string path))//string path - путь к файлу
    while (!read.EndOfStream)
        Console.WriteLine(read.ReadLine());
```

Надеюсь все просто и понятно