# c# как удалить определенную строку из файла

Tags: c#, строки, char

У меня есть текстовый файл и мне нужно удалить строку в которой был обнаружен определенный символ, как можно реализовать такой метод?

Comment: 1) считать все строки из файла в память 2) удалить лишнее из памяти 3) оставшимися строками перезаписать файл

Comment: 1. Читаем построчно файл. 2. Проверяем вхождение заданного символа в строку. 3. Если символ в строке не найден - пишем эту строку в новый файл. 3.1. Если найден - не пишем в новый файл. 4. Удаляем файл исходник. 5. Переименовываем новый файл и файл-исходник.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Построчным чтением текстового файла. Например, тут уже [обсуждались](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356355/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD) методы чтения. Всё что вам нужно - при построчном чтении собирать нужные строки в массив, текстовую переменную, StringBuilder объект и после перезаписать файл результатом.

Answer (score 0):

1. Считать строки var text = file.ReadLine();
2. foreach (var n in text) {
   if (n == "sym") {
   Profit
   }
   }